# Windows 10 Multiple App kiosk not opening required site or showing tiles

Tags: xml, windows, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Kind regards, I'm trying to set up a kiosk by using windows 10 assigned access.

After a whole bunch of messing Around I managed to get a working microsoft edge but it refuses to accept any parameters I added to the referred shortcut. How would one go around to making it open a specific site in kiosk mode? The shortcut itself has the arguments built in but it doesn't seem to go through with kiosk mode. Also my second application is missing on the start layout, here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

<AssignedAccessConfiguration

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/2017/config"

xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"

>

<Profiles>

    <Profile Id="{GUID}">

        <AllAppsList>

            <AllowedApps>

                <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe  " />

                <App DesktopAppPath="c:\pathtoapplication.exe"/>

            </AllowedApps>

        </AllAppsList>

        <StartLayout>

            <![CDATA[<LayoutModificationTemplate xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">

                  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />

                  <DefaultLayoutOverride>

                    <StartLayoutCollection>

                      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">

                        <start:Group Name="KIOSK">

                          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="c:\shortcut\Microsoft Edge.lnk" /> #This shortcut has arguments

                         <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath=" c:\shortcut\application.lnk" />

                        </start:Group>

                      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>

                    </StartLayoutCollection>

                  </DefaultLayoutOverride>

                </LayoutModificationTemplate>

            ]]>

        </StartLayout>

        <Taskbar ShowTaskbar="false"/>

    </Profile>

</Profiles>

<Configs>

    <Config>

        <AutoLogonAccount rs5:DisplayName="Kiosk"/>

        <DefaultProfile Id="{GUID}"/>

    </Config>

</Configs>
```

Maybe the custom third party application requires dependencies or something?

Answer (score 0):

After messing around I found out the issue was that the folder where I placed the applications wasn't accessible for the assigned access user, moving these to the
"%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ folder fixed this.

The reason for edge not starting with the parameters is because it found an existing edge shortcut here aswell.